# Flash builder 4.6. How to reduce the mobile app size for IOS.

Tags: ios, mobile, flex4

I have build an app and its in app store aswell. But the app size is more than 20 mb so it can not be downloaded with out wifi or connecting to computer. How can I reduce the app size? I have unziped the ipa file and checked but there is nothing big which can be reduced. So is there a way to compress it more or do some trick to reduce the size of app.

Answer (score 0):

Under i added some of the ways that used in Flash Builder to optimize and reduce Build Size.

1. If you use custom components make them Model and load through Model Loader.
2. If you are using Flex Builder or the mxmlc command-line compiler, you can set the
   optimize  compiler option to true

   mxmlc -optimize=true MyApp.mxml

   3.When you set the strict compiler option to true, the compiler verifies that definitions 
   and package names in import statements are used in the application.
   4.Implement RSL in your Project - Runtime Shared Libraries
   5.Create SWC file of your common code

Comment: I tried those things but did not work. I am surprised it should have reduced the file size a little bit. now the compile arguments look like this -locale en_US -define=CONFIG::debug,false -optimize=true  _compiler arguments_ copy non-embeded file to pout folder [chekced]. Enable strict type checking [checked]. enable warnings [Checked]

Comment: build path looks like this now. framework linkage = runtime shared library (RSL) **verify RSL digests = checked ** **remove unused RSLs = checked ** use local debug runtime shared libraries when debugging = checked** automatically determine library ordering based on dependecies = checked